# SEBool Persistent Values

Tags: linux, selinux

I am learning how to use **setsebool** and **getsebool**

I am aware that I can set a bool on and off via the command setsebool, for example:

`setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db on`

I can also check the current value using :

`getsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db`

I can also make the change persistent using :

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on`

What I coulnd't find online is: How can I check the current persistent value (not currently applied) that will actually be loaded once the server reboots ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `semanage` to inspect the boolean:

```
# semanage boolean -l
SELinux boolean               State   Default  Description
...
httpd_can_network_connect_db  (off  , off)     Allow httpd to can network connect db
```

The `State` column gives you the current live state. The `Default` column gives you the value loaded at boot time from the policy:

```
# setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db on
# getsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db
httpd_can_network_connect_db on --> on
# semanage boolean -l | grep httpd_can_network_connect_db
httpd_can_network_connect_db  (on   ,  off) Allow httpd to can network connect db
```

When using `setsebool` with the `-P` to make the boolean change persistent, this updates the policy:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
# semanage boolean -l | grep httpd_can_network_connect_db
httpd_can_network_connect_db  (on   ,   on) Allow httpd to can network connect db
```

From the source code of `setsebool`, you can see that persistence is implemented by using the API of `semanage`: [Reference](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux/blob/dca7ce8195d241bf44eb4b158ef2e5d6e3b9963a/policycoreutils/setsebool/setsebool.c#L268).